# How to add new attribute with a custom source to an existing group

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a new attribute with a custom source to an existing group. However, the attribute never appears in the UI.

yes, I've disabled caching and bumped  in my module's config.xml.

Here's the mysql4-upgrade script

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                ->setType('catalog_product')
                ->getTypeId();

$installer->addAttribute($entityTypeId, 'editor_form', array(
        'group'             => 'mygroup',
        'input'             => 'select',
        'type'              => 'int',
        'label'             => 'Editor form',
        'backend'           => '',
        'visible'           => 1,
        'required'          => 0,
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'unique'            => false,
        'apply_to'          => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable',
        'is_configurable'   => false,
        'source'            => 'sourcetype/attribute_source_type',
        'frontend_class'    => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'used_in_product_listing'   => false,
        'sort_order'        => 5,
    ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

And the custom source in app/code/local/mycompany/w2p/Attribute/Source

```
<?php
class mycompany_w2p_Sourcetype_Model_Attribute_Source_Type extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
      return array(
            array('value' => 0, 'label'=>'Standard form'),
            array('value' => 1, 'label'=>'Custom form'),
        );
    }
}
```